# I can't implement pagination. Help implement pagination (VUETIFY or BOOTSTRAP-VUE) with url params

Tags: ecmascript-6, vuejs2, pagination, vuetify.js, bootstrap-vue

Help people! I am unable to implement pagination on vuetify and bootstrap-vue. I have a news portal. After login, it is redirected to the news page. News comes out in the form of a card (). It turns out to be a very long page.

I can't figure out how to make pagination.? How the data will change.? My news comes in the form of an object. I save the data on the vuex store and through the getters I output the data in the component.

Explain and show an example please. There is no good example on the internet. All sources link to the official site. And the official site is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, for news pages and the other massive data, it is recommended to use a lazy load approach. It means you could get about for example 50 objects from your API and when the user scrolled and reached the bottom then you have to load the 50 rest of the news.

[Lazy loading](https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/lazy-loading/) is the practice of delaying load or initialization of resources or objects until they’re actually needed to improve performance and save system resources.

**vuetify has the [v-lazy component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lazy/) and you could use it for your cards.**

Comment: Even for images you could use this approach via vuetify like `lazy-src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/10/6"` . 

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images/#usage